# How do I read redirected stdin from Fortran and C? (Linux/bash/gfortran/gcc)

Tags: c, bash, fortran

I ran into a situation where I had to read `stdin` separately from FORTRAN and C. In the working example I'd post here later, I intend to read `stdin` and print every line immediately.

If I type input in terminal, everything works as expected, e.g.,

```sh
$ ./a.out 

 Enter line 1 from Fortran :  abc
 LINE 1 (abc                           )
 Enter line 2 from C :  def
 LINE 2 (def                           )
```

Whereas if I save my input in a run file and redirect it to `stdin` the program will be broken.

```sh
$ cat runfile 
abc
def
$ ./a.out < runfile 

 Enter line 1 from Fortran :   LINE 1 (abc                           )
 Enter line 2 from C :   LINE 2 (                              )
```

Thank you in advance.

Makefile:

```
## Linux / Bash / gfortran / gcc

a.out: a.o b.o c.o
    gcc a.o b.o c.o -lgfortran -o a.out

a.o: a.f
    gfortran -c a.f -o a.o

b.o: b.c
    gcc -c b.c -o b.o

c.o: c.c
    gcc -c c.c -o c.o
```

FORTRAN source file (a.f):

```
      !! a.f
      subroutine from_fortran
      integer input,iout
      character*30 line
      input = 5
      iout = 6
   10 format (/,' Enter line 1 from Fortran :  ',$)
   20 format (a30)
      write (iout,10)
      read (input,20) line
      write (iout,*) 'LINE 1 (',line,')'
      end
```

C source files (b.c and c.c):

```
/* b.c */
#include <stdio.h>

void from_c() {
   char l2[30] = {0};
   printf(" Enter line 2 from C :  ");
   scanf("%s", l2);
   printf(" LINE 2 (%-30s)\n", l2);
}

/* c.c */
extern void from_fortran_();
extern void from_c();

int main() {
   from_fortran_();
   from_c();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe some buffering issue? If Fortran doesn't buffer input from a terminal but does from a file?

Comment: When you read from the terminal, each call to `read()` returns as soon as a line is entered, and only that line gets buffered. But when you read from any other type of stream, it reads as much as it can and saves it in a buffer.

Comment: C and Fortran each have their own buffered I/O subsystem, so C can't use Fortran's buffer.

Comment: I guess if I call C function first, Fortran cannot use C's buffer either? Any suggestions for workarounds? I'm writing most of the things in C/C++ so it'd be no problem for me to put some hack in my code. Thanks. @Barmar

Comment: In C you can use `setbuf()` to turn off buffering. I'm not sure if there's anything equivalent for Fortran. I found the `BUFFERED` option when opening a file, but I don't know if you can change the buffering of standard input.

Comment: If anyone would be interested in my final solution, I eventually wrote up a `BIND(C)` subroutine in FORTRAN to replace `scanf()`/`std::getline()` in the C/C++ code.

Comment: Firstly note Fortran is officially spelt Fortran (all lower case) and has been for over a quarter of a century, though the style used above shouldn't have been used in new code this millennium. Secondly the Fortran standard says nothing about buffering